# Use resource bundle strings in annotations

Tags: java, annotations

So I'm trying out a cli parsing library named JewelCli that makes defining options pretty easy using annotations. Let's say my option looks like

```
@Option(shortName = "p")
int getPort();
```

So far so good, now I add a description for this option. Since the program has to support multiple languages, the description is taken from a resource bundle:

```
static final String DESC_PORT = ResourceBundle.getBundle("someBundle").getString("someKey");

@Option(shortName = "p",
        description = DESC_PORT)
int getPort();
```

And here comes the catch: non-constant variables are not allowed in annotations, so the code won't compile. Is there any workaround to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to specify at least the bundle name (and perhaps the key) on the annotation; something like:

```
public class BundleDemo {
    private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "Messages";

    @BundleDemo.Message(BundleDemo.BUNDLE_NAME)
    public String foo;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for(Field field : BundleDemo.class.getFields()) {
            Message message = field.getAnnotation(Message.class);
            ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(message.value());
            String value = bundle.getString(field.getName());
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }

    @Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(value = ElementType.FIELD)
    public @interface Message {
        String value();
    }
}
```

*This code assumes a Messages.properties with property* foo *in the root of the classpath.*

Some frameworks (like [Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#default-resolution-algorithm)) define a standard location for message bundles.